# How to upload document's in ACTIVITI(APS 1.8.1) USER FORM from 3rd party web application?

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I have one Web Application developed in .net, through that I am calling post API to start workflow in Alfresco process service, also I am sending some metadata fields and documents from .net portal.

Currently I am able to start workflow and also getting all the metadata from .net application, but facing issue for getting documents from .net to APS.

Please let me know any suggestions or how can I achieve this?

I have found following API to upload document, but that document is not getting assigned to my custom property on property page.

```
/enterprise/process-instances/{processInstanceId}/raw-content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you are using is for attaching a document to process instance. that means you'll only be able to view the document in process documents.

If you want to attach a document to a form-field you'll have to upload the document via the */content/raw* API and pass the `id` received as `value` to your form-field id in the `values` object when init a process or submit your task.